# Creat data label for geom_count

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I am really new to R, and I am now practicing making data visualizations with the "palmerpenguins" package:
I have made the following plot to check the distributions of penguins based on their species and islands:

```
ggplot(data=penguins_raw,mapping=aes(x=Species,y=Island))+
  geom_count(aes(color=after_stat(n)))
```

[image]

However, I would also like to add the data labels to show the count of penguins of each species/island.
I understood that I should use the "geom_text" function, but I have tried but could not write the function correctly.
Really appreciate your help!

The functions I have tried include:
#1:

```
ggplot(data=penguins_raw,mapping=aes(x=Species,y=Island))+
  geom_count(aes(color=after_stat(n)))+
  geom_text(aes(label=n,color = "#ffffff"))
```

#2:

```
ggplot(data=penguins_raw,mapping=aes(x=Species,y=Island))+
  geom_count(aes(color=after_stat(n)))+
  geom_text(aes(label=after_stat(n),color = "#ffffff"))
```

but obviously I am not writting the correct function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_count` uses `stat="sum"` under the hood to compute the "counts", whereas the `stat` defaults to `"identity"` for `geom_text`. Instead, if you want to add the counts displayed by `geom_count` to your chart you have use `stat="sum"` for `geom_text` too. Only then can you use `after_stat` to display the counts as labels:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins)

ggplot(data = penguins_raw, mapping = aes(x = Species, y = Island)) +
  geom_count(aes(color = after_stat(n))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(n)),
    color = "#ffffff",
    stat = "sum"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, when I used the lines below, the colors of my dots turned black. Why could I not keep the gradient blue color in my dots anymore? 'ggplot(data=penguins_raw,mapping=aes(x=Species,y=Island))+
  geom_count(aes(fill=after_stat(n)))+
  geom_text(aes(label=after_stat(n)),stat="sum",vjust=-1.5)'

Comment: You used `fill=after_stat(n)`. The default shape of the "dots" for `geom_count` (and geom_point) has only a `color` aes. Hence use `color = after_stat(n)`. If you need both color and fill (e.g. if you want a different outline color you have to use a different shape, e.g. `shape=21` = filled dots with colored outline.